# JavaScript taking input form and changing HTML forms

Tags: javascript, html

I have customer site with a set of customized procedures that I maintain. We have a process we use for converting energy for a specific calibration. We take a reading, multiply it by an offset, then enter the result into the test form. The page we have only has limited functionality so I am trying to use HTML form as well as JavaScript for the calculations.

Below is what I have but for some reason the result isn't showing up to the right of each of the readings that get entered. I only dabble a little with coding so I'm probably missing something obvious.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>OAI Offset Caclculation</h2>
<script>
    function oaicalc(offset, reading1, reading2, reading3, reading4, reading5) {
//value near 1.000  
        var offset = parseFloat(document.getElementById('offset').value); 
//Energy value in mj 200.0> value <1.000
        var r1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('reading1').value); 
        var r2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('reading2').value);
        var r3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('reading3').value);
        var r4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('reading4').value);
        var r5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('reading5').value);

//Corrected Energy Values
        var o1 = offset * r1;
        var o2 = offset * r2;
        var o3 = offset * r3;
        var o4 = offset * r4;
        var o5 = offset * r5;

//Chage HTML form Output
        document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = o1;
        document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML = o2;
        document.getElementById('output3').innerHTML = o3;
        document.getElementById('output4').innerHTML = o4;
        document.getElementById('output5').innerHTML = o5;
    }
</script>


<form id="oaioffsetform">
  <label for="offset">Offset:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="offset" name="offset" value="0">
  <br>
  <br>
  <label for="reading1">OAI Reading 1:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="reading1" name="reading1" value="0" oninput="oaicalc()">:  <output name="output1">0</output>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label for="reading2">OAI Reading 2:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="reading2" name="reading2" value="0" oninput="oaicalc()">:  <output name="output2">0</output>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label for="reading3">OAI Reading 3:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="reading3" name="reading3" value="0" oninput="oaicalc()">:  <output name="output3">0</output>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label for="reading4">OAI Reading 4:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="reading4" name="reading4" value="0" oninput="oaicalc()">:  <output name="output4">0</output>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label for="reading5">OAI Reading 5:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="reading5" name="reading5" value="0" oninput="oaicalc()">:  <output name="output5">0</output><br><br>
</form> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider using `.valueAsNumber` rather than `parseFloat(value)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: You are referring to the IDs of the output, but the outputs don't have IDs they have NAMES `name="output4"`. Just change name to ID

Comment: @imvain2 The `name` attribute is required on form fields if the field value is intended to be submitted as form data. I would say that the OP should leave the `name` attribute in place and simply change the JavaScript to access the elements via `.querySelector("[name='<theName>']")`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I was referring to the `output` elements. Those are supposed to be showing the data and that is the error and those aren't form fields.

Comment: @imvain2 I see. Nonetheless, the use of  `id`s should be avoided whenever possible (which is almost always) as it causes brittle code that won't scale easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I created a general event listener for input on the form. The input element is the target on the event object. You don't need to parse the value of the input, now that they have the type of number.

If the offset is updated you need to run through all the input elements to calculate a new value.

General comment: use the name attribute for both form and input elements. I makes if easy to find the right element.

```js
document.forms.oaioffsetform.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  if (e.target.dataset.id) {
    let outvalue = e.target.value * form.offset.value;
    form[`output${e.target.dataset.id}`].value = outvalue;
  }
  if (e.target.name == 'offset') {
    [...form.readings.querySelectorAll('input')].forEach(input => {
      let outvalue = input.value * form.offset.value;
      form[`output${input.dataset.id}`].value = outvalue;
    });
  }
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>OAI Offset Caclculation</h2>
<form name="oaioffsetform">
  <label for="offset">Offset:</label><br>
  <input type="number" name="offset" value="0">
  <br>
  <br>
  <fieldset name="readings">
    <label for="reading1">OAI Reading 1:</label><br>
    <input type="number" name="reading1" data-id="1" value="0">: <output name="output1">0</output>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="reading2">OAI Reading 2:</label><br>
    <input type="number" name="reading2" data-id="2" value="0">: <output name="output2">0</output>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="reading3">OAI Reading 3:</label><br>
    <input type="number" name="reading3" data-id="3" value="0">: <output name="output3">0</output>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="reading4">OAI Reading 4:</label><br>
    <input type="number" name="reading4" data-id="4" value="0">: <output name="output4">0</output>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="reading5">OAI Reading 5:</label><br>
    <input type="number" name="reading5" data-id="5" value="0">: <output name="output5">0</output><br><br>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: I very much like this solution! I do appreciated it! Learned a bunch from going over the code too!

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in the comments, your form fields have `name` attributes but you are attempting to access them as if they had `id` attributes. You can access an element by its `name` attribute by using [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
You really should strive to avoid using `id` attributes on elements as their use makes the solution brittle and causes problems with scaling an application down the line. In most cases, you can avoid them completely.

Your HTML is not correct for a few reasons:

- You don't have a `<head>` element in your document.
- The first heading in a document should be `h1` and `h2` would only
  then be used if you were trying to define a sub-section of that `h1`.
  Do not use heading elements because of the way they style the text,
  you can use CSS to alter the styling. Headings are for creating
  document structure that is used by those who  rely on assistive
  technologies, like screen readers to help them navigate the page
  content.
- You should not be using `br` elements to create visual alignment on
  the page. `br` elements are to be used solely to break up a line of
  block level content (i.e., paragraphs, divs, etc.) that must appear
  on the next line down. They should not be used to add white vertical
  space to a page. Again, use CSS for that.
- You should be separating your JavaScript from your HTML and therefore
  [not use inline event attributes like `oninput` in your HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991). Instead,
  do your event binding in JavaScript with [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) should be avoided whenever possible as there are security and performance implications to using it. Since the data you are working with doesn't contain any HTML that needs to be parsed, you should use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

See updated code below:

```css
div { margin-top:.5em; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>OAI Offset Calculation</h1>

<form>
  <div>
    <!-- An alternate way to use <label> elements is to wrap them around the element
         that they are a label for. This way you don't need any ID's. -->
    <label>Offset:<br>
      <input type="number" name="offset" value="0">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>OAI Reading 1:<br>
      <input type="number" name="reading1" value="0">
    </label>
    :  <output name="output1">0</output>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>OAI Reading 2:<br>
      <input type="number" name="reading2" value="0">
    </label>
    :  <output name="output2">0</output>
  </div>
  <div>
   <label>OAI Reading 3:<br>
     <input type="number" name="reading3" value="0">
   </label>
   :  <output name="output3">0</output>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>OAI Reading 4:<br>
      <input type="number" name="reading4" value="0">   
    </label>
    :  <output name="output4">0</output> 
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>OAI Reading 5:<br>
      <input type="number" name="reading5" value="0">
    </label>
    :  <output name="output5">0</output>
  </div>
</form> 

<!-- Your <script> element should be the last thing in the <body> so that
     by the time the HTML parser reaches it, all the HTML elements will
     have been parsed into memory and will be available for use. -->
<script>
  // Use const on element references
  // Get all your element references just once rather than every time the function runs
  // Don't set variables to the property of an element because if you ever want a different
  // proeprty value, you'd need to scan the document again for the same element.
  const r1 = document.querySelector("[name='reading1']"); 
  const r2 = document.querySelector("[name='reading2']");
  const r3 = document.querySelector("[name='reading3']");
  const r4 = document.querySelector("[name='reading4']");
  const r5 = document.querySelector("[name='reading5']");
  const offset = document.querySelector("[name='offset']"); 
  const o1 = document.querySelector("[name='output1']");
  const o2 = document.querySelector("[name='output2']");
  const o3 = document.querySelector("[name='output3']");
  const o4 = document.querySelector("[name='output4']");
  const o5 = document.querySelector("[name='output5']");  
  
  // Set your events up in JavaScript, not HTML
  r1.addEventListener("input", oaicalc);
  r2.addEventListener("input", oaicalc);
  r3.addEventListener("input", oaicalc);
  r4.addEventListener("input", oaicalc);
  r5.addEventListener("input", oaicalc);  

  // You aren't passing anything to this function and your elements are already
  // referenced, so you don't need any function arguments.
  function oaicalc() {
    // Now you only need to get the values and parse them
    let offsetValue = parseFloat(offset.value); 

    // Use .textContent when there is no HTML in the string you are working with
    o1.textContent = offsetValue * parseFloat(r1.value);
    o2.textContent = offsetValue * parseFloat(r2.value);
    o3.textContent = offsetValue * parseFloat(r3.value);
    o4.textContent = offsetValue * parseFloat(r4.value);
    o5.textContent = offsetValue * parseFloat(r5.value);   
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the tips and best practice information. Haven't been in any sort of coding class since like 2001. Been scavenging and picking up things here and there so I miss a lot of that stuff.

Comment: @DariusLunar You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote all helpful answers and consider marking this answer as "the" answer by clicking the checkmark at the top left.